# How to disable a service without using 'systemctl disable'

Tags: systemd

There is a service I want to run only when another service fails (`[Unit] OnFailure=foo`), but I don't want this service (`foo`) to start up automatically on boot. One option is running `systemctl disable foo`, but I'm looking for another way.

Background: I am creating an OS image, and I don't want to have to boot the machine up, run that command (`systemctl disable foo`), then shut it down before declaring my image final.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All services are "disabled" by default; "enablement" is opt-in.

If `foo.service` is your custom service, then it won't be started unless explicitly pulled in by something (like the `OnFailure=` directive), and you should not "disable" anything.

Comment: So basically you "get this functionality for free" unless foo has been enabled previously?

Answer (score 45):

`systemctl enable` works by manipulating symlinks in `/etc/systemd/system/` (for system daemons). When you `enable` a service, it looks at the `WantedBy` lines in the `[Install]` section, and plops symlinks in those `.wants` directories.

`systemctl disable` does the opposite.

You can just remove those symlinks—doing that by hand is fully equivalent to using `systemctl disable`.

Comment: This would be a service that hasn't been run by systemd yet (it's custom), so there wouldn't be any of those extra symlinks. I am guessing those would be created on first boot?

Comment: @Tshepang it shouldn't be enabled unless you enable it manually (or in a script, of course)

Comment: Oh, I assumed it would be enabled automatically (which is something I've come to expect by installing Debian packages). Good to know.

Comment: @Tshepang that's the postinst script in the package doing an enable. Or I guess shipping the symlinks in the package, not sure if they do that.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `systemctl start ServiceName.service` and `systemctl stop Service.Name.service` to start and stop a service respectively. In contrast to `systemctl enable ...` and `systemctl disable ...`, the start and stop commands only last for the current session, therefore when you reboot the machine the changes wont be saved.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the options of masking and unmasking, but someone with more experience and know-how should explain that instead of me.

```
sudo systemctl mask service_to_mask
sudo systemctl unmask service_to_unmask
```

I hope this is correct. But this type of thing needs to be in this conversation for completeness.

Masking uses diversion to `/dev/null` which is pretty nice.

If I remember correctly, services can be stopped, disabled, and masked in the same session.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).